# How to use compact property to show this proof from topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let X be a compact Hausdorff space, {$F_{n}$ | n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$,} a descending collection of closed subsets of X; and O
an open set containing $\cap$$F_{n}$.  Show that $\exists$ N such that $F_{n} $$\subseteq$ O  $\forall$ n $\ge$ N.

Ok I have made some progress: 
- I know all these closed sets are compact as X is compact and any closed set of a compact space is compact (thus every open cover of each closed set has a finite subcover)
- I think maybe using the finite intersection property may be useful

I am looking for a way to approach this problem. How to set it up. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If all sets $F_n\setminus O$ are non-empty, then it contardicts the finite intersection property.

Comment: How does compactness come into it?

Comment: @m.styles Since each $F_n\setminus O$ is a closed subset of a compact Hausdorff space, it is compact.

Comment: If all sets Fn∖O are non-empty does it contradict the finite intersection property of Fn for all n or Fn∖O for all n. This is the bit I am unsure of.

Comment: @m.styles If all sets $F_n\setminus O$ are non-empty then the family $\{F_n\setminus O\}$ of closed sets of the compact space $X$ has the finite intersection property, but has the empty intersection.

Comment: I now understand your argument but showing {Fn\O} has empty intersection is not straight forward to me?

Comment: Also this argument seems to not take into account the space being Hausdorff which surely has to come into play somewhere?

Comment: @m.styles $\bigcap (F_n\setminus O)= (\bigcap F_n)\setminus O=\varnothing$.

Comment: @m.styles The claim holds for all compact spaces, not necessarily Hausdorff  because the finite intersection property (of families of closed subsets) holds for all compact spaces. But Hausdorff compact spaces are much more usual for most topologists.

Comment: If all sets $F_n \setminus O$ are non-empty, it is not the negation of the one we need to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose (by contradiction) that $(n_k)_{k\in \mathbb N}$ is a strictly increasing sequence in $\mathbb N$ such that $F_{n_k}\not \subset O$ for each $k.$ Choose $p_k\in F_{n_k}$ \ $O.$ Let $G_k=\{p_j:j\geq k\}.$ Then $$\emptyset \ne \overline {G_{k+1}}\subset \overline {G_k}\subset \overline {F_{n_k}}=F_{n_k}.$$ Let $G= \cap_{k\in \mathbb N}\overline {G_k}.$ We have $G\ne \emptyset.$ Take any  $p\in G$. Then $p$ belongs to $\cap_{m\in \mathbb N}F_m,$ because for any $m$ we may take $n_k>m,$  and $p\in \cap_{j\geq k}\overline {G_{n_j}} \subset F_{n_k}\subset F_m.$ So  $p\in O.$ But then $O$ is a nbhd of $p,$ with $p\in \overline {G_k}$ (for any $k$), which implies $G_k\cap O\ne \emptyset,$ a contradiction.

Comment: I don't see how this proves anything. I think using compact and Hausdorff property is essential?

Comment: The negation of $\exists n(m>n\implies F_m\subset O)$ is that there exist infinitely many $n$ such that $F_n\not \subset O,$  which implies the existence of $(n_k)_k$ with $F_{n_k}\not \subset O.$  I showed this is untenable.... Each $\overline {G_k}$ is compact because it is closed in the compact $T_2$ space $X$.  And $(\overline {G_k})_k$ is a nested  sequence of non-empty compact  sets in  the  compact $T_2$ space $X$ so $G$ is not empty.